# How do I move websites from one profile to another in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I added several websites to Google Analytics and created an individual profile for each, not realizing what I was doing. How do I move websites from one profile to another?
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, you can’t, but I can’t find a reference at the moment so I won’t post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Google considers profiles as subsets of data of a particular site ([source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts)), so ideally you should have the entire set of data for that site at the web property level, thus being able to delete different profiles for a particular site without losing the original data. Now (and this is pure speculation), I think this is the reason they don’t offer this option/feature. See [this help page](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1102154&topic=1102143&ctx=topic) as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can move your Google Analytics account to a different Google Account by making that Google Account a second administrator to your Analytics account:

1. Sign in to your Google Analytics account
2. Click **Access Manager**
3. From the **Existing Access** table click **Add User**
4. Enter your alternate Google Account's email address, last name, and
   first name
5. Select **Account Admin** as the Access type
6. Click **Finish**

Now you can sign in to your Analytics account as the new administrator, and you can delete the original account administrator, if you choose to.

Answer (score 0):

After spending 20 minutes in the Analytics help section and in my own Analytics account I am fairly sure that there is no way to transfer profiles. Neither on the [start page of the help section](http://support.google.com/analytics/?hl=en#topic=1726911) nor on the [Web Properties, Profiles, and Report Data Basics](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1010249&topic=1009620&ctx=topic) is there any indication that this might be possible.

It appears that the only way to do so would be to delete the profile and then re-create it under the desired account. But then you [lose all your data](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009621&topic=1009620&ctx=topic).